# Detect AJAX Request

Tags: ajax, jquery

On my website I have mouse over and mouse out events set up on an HTML table.  These events trigger ajax requests, and perform certain actions etc.  However, i want to be able to not trigger a second request if one is already running.  So, is there away to detect these requests, and therefore avoid a second.  Incidentally Im using the jQuery `$.ajax()`
if it helps at all.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something simple like:

```
var requestMade = false;

function yourAjaxFunction(){
    if(!requestMade)
    {
        requestmade = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "page",
            success: function(){
                requestMade = false;
            }
            error: function(){
                requestMade = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can use the `success:` and `error:` settings to change the variable back to false.

I have never used the `error` so you may have to include some other things in it, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

For this suppose I'd use [`ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop) which would change specific variable `ajaxRunning` which could be checked before sending the request (maybe in `ajaxStart()` directly?)

Answer (score 0):

Set global or local static variable to true when first ajax is about to trigger, than add if before triggering the second one ;) Than after one request is finished, set this variable to false